# jQuery Tabs - Select tab based on tab text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

Is it possible to do a tab selection based on the title of the tab?  I've got a setup currently that has links pointing to the integer value of the tab, but would like to be able to select the tab just by the String value.

Current change function

```
<a href="javascript:changeTab(3)">Application</a>
function changeTab(tabID) {
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', tabID);
}
```

What I'd 'like' to be able to do

```
<a href="javascript:changeTab('Driver Application')">Application</a>
function changeTab(tabID) {
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', tabID);
}
```

I've found an example on SO that gets the VALUE of the text for the tab, but nothing where it uses a known value to determine the tab that is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. The idea is to get the tab's ID based on its contents and then use the existing tabs API to select it.

```
<a href="javascript:changeTab('Driver Application')">Application</a>
function changeTab(tabContents) {
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', $(".ui-tabs-nav a:contains(tabContents)").attr("href"));
}
```

Comment: Selected answer as it doesn't require a variable creation. Also selected due to the correct jquery DOM(?) item selection...only thing wrong was the .attr("id") needed to be .attr("href") thanks for the answer!  I've changed the function to us the isNaN so that will accept either option

Answer (score 2):

The 'select' method can also take a selector, so if you could bear to use the tab's id, your code might look like:

```
<a href="javascript:changeTab('#driverapplication')">Application</a>
function changeTab(tabID) {
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', tabID);
}
```

Failing that, if you really want to use the tab text itself, you could find the tab and then work backwards to find the id...

```
function changeTab(tabText) {
    var href = $('#tabs li a:contains("' + tabText + '")').attr("href");
    tabs('select', href);
}
```

Tweak to taste, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeTab(sTabContent) {
    var iId = $(".ui-tabs-nav li a:contains('" + sTabContent + "')")
        .parent().index();
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', iId);
}
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/Me879/).